# C++ Multiple Definition of Struct

Tags: c++, struct, linker, header-files, object-files

I have header `util.hpp`  containing a simple struct:

```cpp
// util.hpp

struct Point {
  float x;
  float y;
};
```

Two cpp files, let's call them `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, both include `util.hpp`:

```cpp
// a.cpp

#include "util.hpp"

void funcA(float _x, float _y) {
  Point p;
  p.x = _x;
  p.y = _y;
  // ...
}
```

```cpp
// b.cpp

#include "util.hpp"

void funcB(float _x, float _y) {
  Point p;
  p.x = _x;
  p.y = _y;
  // ...
}

int main() {
  // ...
}
```

When I compile `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` individually and then link them together I get no errors.

Why is that? Since I include `util.hpp` in both files, wouldn't we have a double definition of `struct Point`?
When I for example add a variable definition to `util.hpp` like this:

```cpp
// util.hpp

struct Point {
  float x;
  float y;
};

// New variable
int foo;
```

I get the following error when linking:

```
g++ a.o b.o -o test -O0
b.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `foo'
a.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
```

which makes sense to me, but why doesn't the same error occur for the struct?

Comment: each time you include util.hpp you _define_ the global variable _foo_

Comment: @bruno Yes you are right, "int foo;" is actually a definition, just changed the wording from "declaration" to "definition"

Comment: Finaly I also did an answer to say that and more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> b.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `foo'

having

> ```
> // util.hpp
> ...
> // New variable
> int foo;
> ```

each time you include *util.hpp* you **define** again the global variable foo, producing your error

in the header file just *declare* it (`extern int foo;`) and define it on one source file

There is not the same problem for the *struct Point* because this is a type definition, not a global variable definition

Answer (score 5):

A type definition (`struct`, `union`, `class`, `enum`) is just kind of a "blueprint" for the compiler how to lay out certain things in memory but don't cause the generation of code or symbols on their own.

In C++ you can also have member functions and operators and *static member variables*, however these are technically not *part of* the struct/class but *come with* the struct/class and as such you can globally define them only once.

And just like that global variable definition of `foo` you have there this doesn't work if done in a file included multiple times. But you can safely *declare* them multiple times.

Comment: So a multiple _type_ definition is allowed? Does the linker recognize that it's the same struct in both object files?

Comment: @Kittion: No, multiple type definitions are not allowed inside a single compilation unit. What happens is, that type definitions by themself do not emit anything. And because there's nothing emitted there's nothing for the linker to complain about.